# Android2.3 SIP implementation

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am implementing VoIP using SIP (Android2.3). I have a issue regarding how to make a landline call thru SIP + how to send SMS,MMS using SIP. How should I think to meet my goal.
Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a SIP stack.

You are in luck because since Android 2.3 there is a SIP stack included in the Android framework.

Here is a link to the documentation [Android SIP Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html)

Be aware that the SIP stack provided by google does not work over 3g.

You can also try a fully working SIP Demo Sample on the android developer website.

If not, there is a couple of open source project of SIP clients: SIPDroid, CSIPSimple, etc

Hope this helps.
Cheers