# Streaming audio with Sip stack does not work on 3G network in Android 2.3?

Tags: android, stack, sip, 3g

I have developed a simple client sip application on andorid by using SipDemo example which is provided by Google.

My application(everything such as Authentication, Streaming, ...) works perfect over my WiFi network, but when I switch it in 3G network, just authentication of SIP session works fine and the audio streaming does not work!!??

By the way I have a desktop client SIP application(written in C#) that works perfect with my android client app over 3G network, it means that streaming does not work when two client is android in 3G network, but when one of clients changes to my desktop SIP client application(written by C#) streaming works perfectly.

Does any body run SIP stack which provided in android 2.3 in 3G network?
in the following links it's been told that Sip Stack does not work in 3G network, if so why I can use SIP in 3G network when one client is SipDemo and another is c# client in windows desktop application?

[Android2.3 SIP implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139718/android2-3-sip-implementation)
[Why does the native SIP stack included in Android 2.3 does not work over 3g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219107/why-does-the-native-sip-stack-included-in-android-2-3-does-not-work-over-3g)

Answer (score 0):

It is, for some reason, limited in the software. There is an explicit setting somewhere in the ROM build for this (see [here](http://android.modaco.com/topic/327770-using-gingerbread-internet-calling-sip-without-wifi/)). Probably this is done by Google in pressure from various mobile phone operators... to try to keep there business model of selling minutes rather than bulk data.

Why does it work when one side is not an android phone on 3g? I'm not sure, probably because of a bug in the implementation of the SW lock.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have already changed the mentioned flag, but got the same problem :(